# Converting Layered .ai to PDF via PHP

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, imagick, adobe-illustrator

I've a .ai file with 2 Layer Groups and I want to pipe them into a .pdf file with layers. I already tried ImageMagick but I can't get the selector.
I tried this:

```
exec("convert 'test.ai[0]' output0.png");
exec("convert 'test.ai[1]' output1.png");
```

The First one gives me the whole document. I tried .png for a faster preview of the content first. Anyone have a clue how to handle this? The PDF File will contain more informations then the .ai later.
Friendly regards
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Layer 0 is always the "all lower layers combined" layer.

Comment: But why, if I put layer 1 or 2 as layer parameter it dont create a file. If I set 0 I succesfully get a pdf but at 1 or 2 I don't.